# How would an execution by impalement be carried out at a modern US prison?

Tags: law

Let's suppose that a crazy murderer demands the right to be executed by [longitudinal impalement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impalement#Longitudinal_impalement). He wins the court cases over it, and the judges - after all, *he* is the one who wants it. The judges say "why not" and order the wardens of his penitentiary to prepare for his execution.

To clarify - the murderer demands to be *sat upon a stake vertically without any form of anaesthesia.*

The question is:

**How would the staff of a modern American prison organize and perform the execution of an offender by means of longitudinal impalement? How would the procedure differ from the medieval practice? How can viewing of the execution be accomodated?**

Comment: Judges  *don't* say 'why not?' in death cases. That's grounds for appeal.

Comment: It doesn't work this way, not in the U.S.A. nor in any other country. There is a very short list of forms of execution which are allowed, and if there is anything to choose it is the judge who chooses not the criminal. And if I remember correctly, there is something in the constitution of the U.S.A. about "cruel and unusual punishments"  -- impalement is certainly "unusual" in American context.

Comment: They would stick a needle into his ass. I'm not American and have done no research but I doubt they could order the penitentiary workers who usually execute the sentence to do it this way because it might go against their human rights. And then there are also the extra costs. It would probably mean extra procedures to be written, training to be designed and given and attended, finished by an examination that they can perform it correctly. I.e. not worth to do it only once.

Comment: I think this is a very interesting question. There are not nearly enough law questions here imo. However, for such a complex idea you have included very little information. Could you maybe offer more details on those court cases?

Comment: Why not asking "Should the stake be sterilized before the execution?"

Comment: While I agree the premise to this question is flawed, I disagree this is story-based. Designing a procedure for a form of execution and addressing the legal ramifications of that procedure seems a valid worldbuilding topic. Discussing how that procedure would be carried out would be the story.

Comment: My opinion about this: if the justice system is crazy enough to allow this, anything can happen.

Comment: *a crazy murderer demands the right*  The word **crazy** means that he would not even be considered sane under law and just on it's own would be grounds for appealing such a death sentence.  And in all likelihood the judge would be impeached for "Why not ?" and not ordering a mental health examination into someone crazy enough to want to die, particularly like that.  It's also hard to see how someone willing to carry out such an execution would not be considered a psychopath, which pretty much rules out that being done.

Answer (score 3):

There are some big hurdles you need to overcome/guard against to get to the point where Death Row is required to make this happen.

First, the death penalty can only be granted if the accuser (normally the prosecutor) demands it as a sentence.  If there is no demand, the guilty cannot himself demand it.  Then, of the 31 states that have the Death Penalty, 29 require a jury to uphold the sentence of death during the sentencing phase (the jury has already decided he is guilty of a sentence that is open to the death penalty).  Of those 29, all but one require a unanimous vote that the guilty be put to death.  If the jury is hung (at least one juror will not vote to make it unanimous in deciding), in four of those states, the penalty phase of the trial is declared a mistrial and a new jury is seated to determine the sentance.  In two states, a hung jury put the decision in the trial judge's hand.  In the remaining 22 states (and the Federal level jurisdiction) that require this hurdle, a Hung Jury results in life in prision, even if it's only one contrary vote.

Alabama requires 10 out of the 12 to concur and will result in a retrial if the deadlock is 3 or more contrary votes (of the penalty phase only, I think?).  Nebraska empanels a three panel judicial committee to decide the sentencing, and a single vote against will result in life in prison.  Montana is the only US state that allows the trial judge sole discretion in the sentancing.

At no point in any of these steps is the guilty man's opinions on method of death considered.  This will need to be addressed some how and explained how this happened.

**BUT WAIT, THERE'S MORE!**

So assuming we got the guilty verdict and the guilty's preferred method of execution.  Now we go to Direct Review.  Unlike any other crime, the guilty has no say in filing an appeal... it's an automatic process that comes with the death penalty.  The trial court's decision is scrutinized for review and to make sure that the death penalty is truly an applicable crime.  Any judge in this step up to the jurisdiction's Supreme Court can easily declare some problem with the judge going along with the convict's harsher sentence and overturn it.

Again, judges are not all cruel and finding one that cannot be convinced this is right should not be to hard.

If he can clear this, there are a few more legal steps that can be used to aid the convict and get him off a death penalty.  These would likely not happen in your story because they are not automatically triggered by the conviction, but by the guilty's own petition for them.  Since this is your guy's desired outcome, we can make the assumption that they are not going to file, but if he was convicted by the Feds, he only has one level to overturn the conviction, which is the Federal Habeas Corpus, while a conviction by a state has two (the state level equivalent of the Federal Habeas Corpus and the Federal one if that fails).  In addition, if all of those fail, he still can appeal his case of methods on constitutional grounds, which will stay his trial until the outcome is determined (for the first filing.  The second one looks to see if he is likely to win).

**How will he be killed**

Most states (and the Feds) will use Lethal Injection exclusively.  The prisoner will have no say in the matter.  Beyond that, 12 states will give the guilty person a choice, but they are limited.  You will either be offered the Lethal Injection... OR:

*Electrocution:  In Alabama, Arkansas, Florida, Kentucky, South Carolina, Tennessee and Virginia

*Gas Chamber:  In Arizona and California

*Firing Squad:  Utah

*Hanging:  Washington (state).

Five out of twelve states (Arizona, Arkansas, Kentucky, Tennessee and Utah) will only extend this offer to inmates convicted of crimes committed prior to a specified date, often the date Lethal Injection was switched to as the primary method.  You are not allowed any creative license in how the state kills you.

Please not that all of these are issues your story should address before you need to get to the healthy and safety of the implementation of the execution.  The fact that this method has to my knowledge never been used in the United States at any point in its existence is further evidence of the 8th Amendment issues it raises.  I have no idea how it would be made safer since for a modern use and if public viewing would be allowed (Lethal injection is only view-able by invitation only, and is normally extended to the family of the convict and the victims and their families, along with a few other legal witnesses (such as a report from a paper).